# Asp.Net MVC Combine and remove inline scripts during response

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, httpresponse, minify

I have been doing some performance analysis on a few websites I am working on and I am noticing that a big problem is the inline scripts.  For the external scrips I wrote an http handler which combines, minifies, and gzips the javascript into one file.  This is then stored  for reuse later by hashing the filenames.

What I am wondering (not sure if this is a good idea but I am posting to get some feedback) is if I remove all script elements with script text inside them and combine them into a single file. I then use the same process I am using for the external scripts and combine them into a single script.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline script always gets inside the page so needs to be traversed by every post or get to and from the server. Since you're using MVC it's quite easy to only have non obtrusive script files in your project as you have quite some control over the rendered html.

You also want to check out [SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/05/26/SquishIt-The-Friendly-ASPNET-JavaScript-and-CSS-Squisher.aspx).

Grz, Kris.

Comment: I know that I would have to traverse the page at every request but I am wondering if the benefit of removing all the inline scripts and thus removing a lot of blocking in the page would outweigh that performance hit. Steve Souders said as much in a few of his talks http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52gL93S3usU&NR=1.  He talks of minimizing inline scripts but I want to eliminate them.

I have implemented a solution similar to SquishIt which uses the Closure Compiler http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/.

Comment: It depends on the bandwidth and the amount of inline script you have. Separate css files can be cached by a browser so they only count for the first time hit. Inline script however mostly traverses the line back and forth several times. If you have many of that it could slow down the app. I suggest you try to find the most common pieces of inline script which you can take away and use a tool like __YSlow__ to measure the optimizations.

Comment: I have been basing a lot of my metrics off of YSlow but I will just try this out and post my results later.  I just need to think of a good way to minimize the times I have yank the inline scripts out of the rendered page.  It would be optimal if I could do this at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to minify and bundle inline javascripts in with external files.

As I mentioned here [Minify inline javascript during build for ASP.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947407/minify-inline-javascript-during-build-for-asp-net/13686181#13686181)

> With templated Razor helpers you could create an extension method like
>   the one below:
>
> ```
> public static MvcHtmlString AddScriptSource(this HtmlHelper helper, Func<dynamic, HelperResult> source, string key)
> {
>     string scriptSource = source(null).ToHtmlString();
>
>     // Cache scriptSource here
>
>     return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
> }
> ```
>
> Which you would use like this:
>
> ```
> @Html.AddScriptSource(@<text>$(document).ready(function() { $('h1').text('The current controller is @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()'); });</text>, "test")
> ```